# Awkward grammar on new flag dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, grammar, flag-dialog

After the minor overhaul of the flag dialog, I noticed this grammar:

[image]

"is... spam" and "is... inappropriate" makes sense to me, but **"is... should be closed"** feels awkward.

---

**Update**: Now it's "as", but the awkward grammar remains.

Comment: Other than that, I like the UI change!

Comment: A *that* before *this* would also be a good idea.

Comment: Obviously it should be "as..."

Comment: Oh, but wait...Even "I'm flagging to report this question is spam/inappropriate/a dupe/in need of..." is incorrect grammar. As @Shadow said, it should be *as* and it's a typo.

Comment: [The post on meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290915/3717023) where this was hashed out (not thoroughly enough, it seems).

Comment: Maybe they could say "needing closure" so it fits with "as"?

Comment: Or “as... it should be closed.” That seems less awkward than it is now, at least.

Comment: "something something" covers both bases

Comment: I can't see why it's awkward, sorry. The only bug was "is" instead of "as".

Comment: This is _not_ [tag:status-completed]. @Shog please get agreement before saying that you satisfied a request! In this case, it is not yet fixed.

Comment: @Lightness, please find something useful to do. Shadow had the only non-awful suggestion for *improving* this here, so I implemented it - if you don't like it, then come up with a better option.

Answer (score 1):

[**As** Shadow Wizard suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254106/awkward-grammar-on-new-flag-dialog#comment829777_254106), we've replaced "is" with **as**.

Comment: Changing it to "as" did not fix the awkward grammar. How does this answer the question?

Comment: I concur - I like "as" for the other options, but "as should be closed" is still awkward and wrong. Perhaps go with what Troyen suggested? ("as needing closure")

Comment: Closure? Are we talking about a missing person or someone on MH370 now?

Comment: "to be" fits the show because we all know should is the angry relative we all have at the dinner table

Comment: @Shog looks like it should be [tag:status-declined], OP here want to change the whole wording.

Comment: Perhaps we just need to change "should be closed" to "it should be closed" now.

Comment: @RobertLongson: Heh, nice save.